# How can I export issues from IBM Cloud's Git Repos and Issue Tracking

Tags: ibm-cloud, gitlab, devops-services

I have a project on IBM Cloud's Git Repos and Issue Tracking service (built on GitLab CE) at https://git.ng.bluemix.net.  I'd like to export the issues in my project for reporting purposes, but I don't see any option provided in the project UI.  Is there some way to export my project's issues into a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

[At the moment, exporting GitHub issues to CSV appear to only be supported in Enterprise editions of GitLab.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/csv_export.html)

However, there appear to be third party options for Community Edition. See the thread [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/5747) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a blog post on this on IBM developer works, entitled [Getting Data from your IBM Cloud GitHub Project](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2017/getting-data-ibm-cloud-github-project/).  The blog is short, its a quick read.

The the code I used (Python 2.7) is out on GitHub, in a project called [IBMCloud_GitLab_CSV](https://github.com/dtoczala/IBMCloud_GitLab_CSV).  It probably doesn't do exactly what you want, but the code is pretty simple and it does dump the data into a CSV file which you can use.